# Number of ordered triplets (x,y,z) satisfying the given inequality

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, products, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

> If $x,y,z>0$ and $x(1-y)>{1\over 4}$ , $y(1-z)>{1\over 4}$ , $z(1-x)>{1\over 4}$ then find the number of order triplets (x,y,z) satisfying the above inequaltiy.

I am stuck as I know how to deal with inequalities in two variables graphically or otherwise but I could not expand that approach to work with this question.

Could someone please help with how to proceed in this ?

Thanks.

One not so standard way I could think of was since the inequalities are symmetric so x=y=z should be satisfied by its solutions , putting this I got that there are no solution, and the answer of the question is also 0 . But this does not seem to be a nice solution

Comment: One not so standard way I could think of was since the inequalities are symmetric so x=y=z should be satisfied by its solutions , putting this I got that there are no solution, and the answer of the question is also 0 . But this does not seem to be a nice solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can get an inequality of two variables, which you know, by the following way.

By AM-GM $$\prod_{cyc}x(1-y)=\prod_{cyc}x(1-x)\leq\prod_{cyc}\left(\frac{x+1-x}{2}\right)^2=\frac{1}{64}.$$ 
Can you end it now?

Comment: Wonderful solution, yes I can continue, thanks!